# android sqlite delete row not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having an odd problem deleting rows from a sqlite database. The first time I try deleting a row, it seems to work fine. However, anytime thereafter, I get no errors, it simply does not remove the selected row. If I uninstall the app and re-run it from eclipse (I have my tablet hooked up to my pc for testing) then the first delete works again.

Here is the code that I am using to populate a Gallery View from my database

```
Cursor cursor = _garmentAdapter.fetchAllLooks();

      cursor.moveToLast();
     final ArrayList<Bitmap> al = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
      _labels=new ArrayList<String>();
      int totalGarments=0;
      for(int i=cursor.getCount()-1; i>=0; i--) {


        totalGarments++;
        Bitmap bd=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(3));
        String label=cursor.getString(1);
        al.add(bd);
        _labels.add(label);



       cursor.moveToPrevious();
      }

      Toast.makeText(BrowseLooks.this, "ITEMS=="+totalGarments,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This toast message is displaying the number of items on screen. For example, if I create 3 items, then delete 1, it shows 2 on screen and the toast says ITEMS==2. However, if I delete another one, I still have 2 items on screen and ITEMS==2. So it seems the cursor is working correctly, but the database is not.

Here is the code for the delete row in the database:

```
return mDb.delete(LOOKS_TABLE, KEY_ROWID+"="+rowId, null)>0;
```

I have also logged rowId as being correct when mDb is called.

Once again, I am not getting any errors, the code is just not working. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem. I did not fully understand the autoincrement of the sqlite database. Because of that, I was deleting rows that were already empty. The way the database increments is to create an entry higher than all previous entries not just the current highest entry. Therefore, the indexes of my on-screen items did not correspond to the indexes in my database table.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
db.delete(LOOKS_TABLE, KEY_ROWID+ " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) });
```

Comment: I will try this this afternoon. Can you explain why this code might work where the code I am using does not?

Comment: I just tried the suggestion above, and it does't have any impact. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: String table = "beaconTable";
String whereClause = "_id"+"=?";
String[]whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(row)};
db.delete(table, whereClause , whereArgs);

Comment: Thank you. I am assuming that for my example, I would substitute beaconTable with the name of my table and row with rowId? Also, I don't mean to ask too much; but could you provide any explanation of why this code will behave differently than the code I have? Once again, thank you very much and I will try this as soon as I can.

Comment: I used the suggestion above and I stil get the same result.

Comment: I have just noticed also that when the database does delete something it seems to be off by 1. For example, I create items 1, 2, 3. I then select item 2 for deletion, the id of this item is 1 (0 based). I click delete. The item 1 gets deleted instead leaving items 2 and 3. I then no longer can delete any items.